# Cannot Read Property Of Send Of Undeifined (distube npm) Event Handler

Tags: javascript, discord.js, audio-player, ytdl, distube

So, I tried making an event handler for the music events (below) and the events load. But Once I starting a song, the event loads, even though the message may be defined it is saying that send is undefined.

Distube Event Handler Below:

```
    const Distube = require(`distube`)

    client.distube = new Distube(client, { searchSongs: false, emitNewSongOnly: true});

    const music = fs.readdirSync(`./music`).filter(file => file.endsWith(`.js`));

    for (const file of music){
        console.log(`Loading Music Event: ${file}`);
        const event = require(`./music/${file}`);
        client.distube.on(file.split(".")[0], event.bind(null, client));
    }
```

Below Is The Event File Which Is Under ./music/playSong (I made playSong as a test event, to see if it would work)

```
    const Discord = require(`discord.js`)
module.exports = (message, queue, song) => {
    message.channel.send(`Playing \`${song.name}\` - \`${song.formattedDuration}\`\nRequested by: ${song.user}}`)
}
```

Full Error Below:

```
(node:9000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at module.exports (E:\SoftwareGithubRep\MoosacBot\music\playSong.js:3:17)
```

Any Help Would Be Appreciated

Comment: It looks like you only supplied the first argument to the module, and it's client. Did you mean to pass all 4 of the arguments through bind() so the module can get all 3 required arguments?

Comment: No, so each event would have their own different arguments, a client. I think null defined the other variables but I am not too sure as I am new. A normal event handler only required that. Also the arguments are recognized with console.log. They are just not when I try message.channel.send()

Comment: Well, apparently channel is not a property on message, causing this error. According to [MDN docs for bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), I don't think that's the correct usage.